# parse json using a bash script without external libraries

Tags: bash

I have a fresh ubuntu installation and I'm using a command that returns a JSON string. I would like to send this json string to an external api using curl. How do I parse something like `{"foo":"bar"}` to an url like `xxx.com?foo=bar` using just the standard ubuntu libraries?

Comment: `python` should be in a "standard" Ubuntu installation. Use that for parsing `JSON` files.

Comment: This is the most sane approach. Check out the `json` python library.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
curl -s 'http://twitter.com/users/username.json' | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^text/ {print $2}'
```

You could use **tr -d '{}**' instead of **sed**. But leaving them out completely seems to have the desired effect as well.

if you want to strip off the outer quotes, pipe the result of the above through **sed 's/(^"\|"$)//g'**